# Clicked item updates other items in the recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

> I have a recycler view which contains a checkbox on click of the check
>   box I update the value for quantity.The problem is if I select the
>   first checkbox in my recycler view for some instances even the 5th
>   check box gets auto checked.

Following is my code for onActivityResult where I call updateBooks which is responsible for handling the click event.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    search_info.clear();
    book_type.clear();


    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            getBookData(data);


            if (books_list.size() > 0) {

                books_list.clear();
                mAdapter.swap(prepareData());
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            updateBooks(recyclerView);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    }
}
```

Following is the code for updateBooks.

```
  private void updateBooks(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

        mAdapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), prepareData(), recyclerView, qty, new DataAdapter.OnItemCheckListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheck(BooksInfo item, DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder) {

                if (qty.equals("") || qty.equals(null)) {
                    viewHolder.tv_qty.setText("0");
                } else {

                    viewHolder.tv_qty.setText(qty);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onItemUncheck(BooksInfo item, DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder) {


                viewHolder.tv_qty.setText("0");
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
```

And this is my Adapter code.

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
    private ArrayList<BooksInfo> books;
    private Context ctx;
    private String qty;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public DataAdapter()
    {

    }
    @NonNull
    public OnItemCheckListener onItemCheckListener;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BooksInfo> books, RecyclerView recyclerView,String qty, OnItemCheckListener onItemCheckListener) {
        this.books = books;
        this.ctx = context;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.onItemCheckListener =onItemCheckListener;
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;

    }

   public interface OnItemCheckListener {
        void onItemCheck(BooksInfo item,ViewHolder viewHolder);
        void onItemUncheck(BooksInfo item,ViewHolder viewHolder);
    }

    public void swap(ArrayList<BooksInfo> datas){
        datas = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.removeAllViews();
        books.clear();
        books.addAll(datas);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {



        final BooksInfo booksInfo = (BooksInfo) books.get(i);

        viewHolder.tv_title.setText(booksInfo.getTitle());
        viewHolder.tv_price.setText(booksInfo.getPrice());
        viewHolder.tv_vol_no.setText(booksInfo.getVol_no());
        viewHolder.tv_status.setText(booksInfo.getStatus());
        viewHolder.tv_isbn.setText(booksInfo.getISBN());
        viewHolder.tv_book_id.setText(booksInfo.getBook_id());
        viewHolder.tv_brand.setText(booksInfo.getBrand());
        viewHolder.tv_sku.setText(booksInfo.getSku());

        viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                viewHolder.cb_selection.setChecked(!(viewHolder.cb_selection.isChecked()));
                if (viewHolder.cb_selection.isChecked()){
                    onItemCheckListener.onItemCheck(booksInfo,viewHolder);
//                    viewHolder.tv_qty.setText(qty);
                }else{
                    onItemCheckListener.onItemUncheck(booksInfo,viewHolder);
//                    viewHolder.tv_qty.setText("0");
                }

            }
        });


    }

    public void updateNotes(ArrayList notesList) {
        books = notesList;
    }


    public void updateQty(String q)
    {
        qty =q;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return books.size();
    }




    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView tv_title,tv_price,tv_vol_no,tv_status,tv_isbn,tv_book_id,tv_brand,tv_sku,tv_qty;
        public CheckBox cb_selection;
        View itemView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.itemView = itemView;

            tv_title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            tv_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
            tv_vol_no = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_volno);
            tv_status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
            tv_isbn = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_isbn);
            tv_book_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_bookid);
            tv_brand = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_brand);
            cb_selection = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_selection);
            cb_selection.setClickable(false);
            tv_sku = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sku);
            tv_qty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_qty);
        }

        public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views in RecyclerView are reusable and you must store checked state outside the view. Add boolean field to your BookInfo class like `public boolean isCkecked`. And change some code inside `onBindViewHolder`:

```
viewHolder.cb_selection.setChecked(booksInfo.isChecked);
viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                booksInfo.isChecked = !booksInfo.isChecked;
                viewHolder.cb_selection.setChecked(booksInfo.isChecked);
                if (booksInfo.isChecked){
                    onItemCheckListener.onItemCheck(booksInfo,viewHolder);
//                    viewHolder.tv_qty.setText(qty);
                }else{
                    onItemCheckListener.onItemUncheck(booksInfo,viewHolder);
//                    viewHolder.tv_qty.setText("0");
                }

            }
        });
```